# What are the leiningen default repositories?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Leiningen (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) looks into some default repositories to satisfy the dependencies specified in your project.clj.

I want to browse these repositories to see what's available out-of-the-box in leiningen. What are these repos and where can I look them up for my specific version of leiningen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of October 2020, leiningen uses the following default repositories:

- "central" - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
- "clojars" - https://repo.clojars.org/

They are hardcoded into leiningen in the namespace `leiningen.core.project` as a [`default-repos`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2.9.4/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L311-L312) dictionary.

Comment: It appears the file is now at https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj and it only includes the first and last repos in the default-repositories list.

Comment: The repos formerly hosted as "clojure" and "clojure-snapshots" are now dead - they contained very old releases of clojure and clojure-contrib from prior to releases being pushed to Maven central.

Comment: Updated:https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj